# Spring data binder ordering

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to find out if there is a way to enforce the order in which setter methods are called during the binding phase of Spring form's submission.

For example, I have a POJO that contains a field that reflects the state of the object, and different portions of the POJO are loaded based on the state of this variable. I have tried moving the field to be the first field in the POJO, I've tried the @Order annotation as well, to no avail.

Is there a way to change the order in which fields are bound to their POJO or am I going about this completely wrong and there is no way to control this?

Thanks

**Updated**
So the scenario I am facing is I am reusing tiles for the login and the account creation pages. In a new site, when customers are purchasing software, they are able to select the mode of delivery (existing account, new account or other). So I have a @ModelAttribute PurchasingDTO like below;

```
public class PurchasingDTO {

// used by the Login
@Valid
private AuthorizationDTO auth;

// use by account creation
@Valid
private AccountDTO account;

@Order(Integer.MIN_VALUE)
private AssociationTypes typeOfAssociation;

//... getter setters etc such as this
  public void setUsername(String username) {
    if (isNew()) {
        this.account.setUsername(username);
    } else if (isExisting()) {
        this.auth.setUsername(username);
    }
  }
 }
```

Notice the use of isNew() and isExisting() which directs the setting of the field. I think this approach is very wrong (clearly) based on not being able to define the setter call order.

The reason for including the 2 objects even though there is overlap in the fields (technically do not need the AuthorizationDTO here as the AccountDTO has the same fields plus others) is due to the validation framework. I was not able to use the "groups" portion of the validation annotations with Spring.

Forgive me as I am new to front-end Spring.

Comment: My guess is that they're called either in the order submitted in the request or in `HashMap` iteration order. If you could provide a more detailed example (particularly of why this would be useful), it might be possible to find an approach or put in a feature request.

Comment: Basically there is no guarantee.. The order the setters are called in is the order the servlet container decides to return the parameters from the request. This might be the order they are submitted in but that isn't a guarantee. Basically there is no way to do it in a consistent way. I would strongly reconsider your design here as it looks too brittle to me, depending on the order of how/when properties are set isn't a very good design in my book...

Comment: I've updated the question with the scenario I am facing, perhaps that will help lead me in the proper direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments there is no way to do this at the time of writing.

The way I worked around the problem was I redesigned my underlying POJO's so there was not duplicated fields. I continue to track the state of the pojo the same way and the service layer knows what to do with what data given the state.

Hope this helps someone else.